# How to animate text in SVG (possibly without using javascript)

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I doing SVG animation of some physical process using [svg](/questions/tagged/svg) (basically I want whole animation as a single `svg` file).

Example can be seen here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/public-bucket-vzi0CDPFDE4ywJfvfylfpnDW/dwg.svg .

Now I'd like to add label stating: "Time: 1.23ns" displaying current time. I couldnt find any obvioius way to replace contents of text object, insert format current time inside text element.

It would also be great if this animation wasn't using javascript, just SVG animation.

Comment: This might help: http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1643 (it uses JavaScript to generate the text, since you can't do that with SMIL alone, but you can have it embedded).

Comment: Definetely worth a try!